Proper way to update records using EF with detached entities
I'm really struggling with getting this working when it feels like it should be super simple.
I've added a cache to my service layer for data returned from EF.
When an entity is returned from EF and updated, it's state is EntityState.Modified.
When it's returned from cache it's state is EntityState.Detached, which all makes sense.
I call DbContext.Update if the entity is Detached and this works fine for all non-navigation properties.
For a tracked entity, I can update the FK ID property directly, but if it started out as detached, it must be updated via the navigational property. Which, for some reason, also causes an UPDATE statement to be run for every single related entity no just the many-to-many table which I would expect.
Tracked entity:
// This will save to the DB
job.PrimaryAccountId = 123;

Initially detached entity:
// This will NOT save to the DB
job.PrimaryAccountId = 123;

// This will not save to the DB
job.PrimaryAccount.AccountId = 123;

Update and save after either of the above:
await _dataAccess.Update(job);
await _dataAccess.SaveChangesAsync();


Are you sure the row exists in the database? Otherwise you should use Add.

@PoulBak Positive. I'm using the same existing row and changing the code and I can see one way works and the other doesn't.
var rowsChanged = await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync(); I'm also checking the return value to see and it returns 0 when it doesn't update and 1 when it does. Also verifying in the DB directly

See here three ways updating an entity: Identity Resolution in EF Core

@AlexanderPetrov Thanks! I've read every MS article but this one :) Looks like SetValues will allow me to use disconnected properties without Update blindly marking everything as modified I'll just need to keep a copy of the original values.

The final paragraph of Steve's answer sums it up for me; caching is for speeding up reading, not writing. Fetch from the source of truth or make a direct update in an write situation rather than faffing trying to reattach a cached entity in the hopes EF will figure out what you wanted to do with it.

This operation should be considered illegal, so doing this in the cached instance would be quite bad if that instance was tracked.
job.PrimaryAccount.AccountId = 123;

Your goal would be to associate the job to a different account, not update an existing account to change it's ID. (If PK, that isn't allowed)
Dealing with detached entities can get messy. Dealing with detached entity graphs (related entities) will certainly get even messier.
If you have loaded a Job and it's associated Primary Account and detached these references in your cache then re-attaching these will cause problems. For instance if I do the following:
var job = _context.Jobs.Include(x => x.PrimaryAccount).Single(x => x.JobId == jobId);

... then I cached that, and some code updates the job:
var job = _cachedJobs.First(x => x.JobId == jobId);
job.PrimaryAccountId = newAccountId;

Now we have a problem. The Job has a navigation property pointing to the old Account, but we changed the Job's FK. If you want to update a detached entity, you need to first remove any navigation property references before calling Update:
var job = _cachedJobs.First(x => x.JobId == jobId);
job.PrimaryAccount = null;
job.PrimaryAccountId = newAccountId;

.. From here you would be Ok to call:
_context.Update(job);

However if you need/want the associated account in the cached copy, you need to re-fetch the associated entities to update that cached job entry.
Ultimately I do not recommend caching entities externally, but instead loading entities on demand and updating their tracked references. Caching introduces more problems than it might appear to solve. Update() automatically will overwrite all values for an entity, not just the values that change, and will execute an UPDATE statement even if nothing actually changed. You are also exposing the system to stale data overwrites or more frequent concurrency exceptions.
The justification for introducing caching is almost always to avoid extra round trips to the database. This is certainly valuable for Read operations, but should not be a factor for Update operations. Fetching a single entity, and even it's related data is very fast, helps detect and avoid stale data overwrites, and makes updating efficient through the change tracker, generating an Update statement for only the values that change, if anything actually changes.
